# Ecto.Query joins generates far too many INNER JOIN

Tags: elixir, inner-join, ecto

Not sure why Ecto is returning the incorrect result. 
I might be messing things up with joins

This is my Ecto.Query

```
from u in User, 
        join: c in assoc(u, :companies), 
        join: r in assoc(c, :roles), 
        join: a in assoc(r, :assets), 
        where: u.id == ^2 and a.id == ^1, 
        group_by: [c.id, u.id, r.id], 
        select: {u.email, u.id, r.name, c.name}
```

It generates:

```
    SELECT u0."email", u0."id", r2."name", c1."name" 
FROM "users" AS u0 
INNER JOIN "access_lists" AS a4 ON a4."user_id" = u0."id" 
INNER JOIN "companies" AS c1 ON a4."company_id" = c1."id" 
INNER JOIN "access_lists" AS a5 ON a5."company_id" = c1."id" 
INNER JOIN "roles" AS r2 ON a5."role_id" = r2."id" 
INNER JOIN "access_lists" AS a6 ON a6."role_id" = r2."id" 
INNER JOIN "assets" AS a3 ON a6."asset_id" = a3."id"
 WHERE ((u0."id" = $1) AND (a3."id" = $2)) 
GROUP BY c1."id", u0."id", r2."id" [2, 1]
```

The result of this query is incorrect

this is the correct query:

```
SELECT u0.email, u0.id, r2.name, c1.name, a6.asset_name , a6.id as asset_id
FROM users AS u0 
INNER JOIN access_lists AS a4 ON a4.user_id = u0.id 
INNER JOIN assets AS a6 ON a4.asset_id = a6.id 
INNER JOIN companies AS c1 ON a4.company_id = c1.id 
INNER JOIN roles AS r2 ON a4.role_id = r2.id 
WHERE ((u0.id = 2) AND (a6.id = 1)) 
Group By u0.id, r2.id, c1.id, a6.id
```

Here is the schemas:

AccessList:

```
  schema "access_lists" do
        belongs_to :user, Db.User
        belongs_to :role, Db.Role
        belongs_to :asset, Db.Asset
        belongs_to :project, Db.Project
        belongs_to :company, Db.Company

        timestamps()
    end
```

User:

```
many_to_many :roles, Db.Role, join_through: Db.AccessList
many_to_many :assets, Db.Asset, join_through: Db.AccessList
many_to_many :projects, Db.Project, join_through: Db.AccessList        
many_to_many :companies, Db.Company, join_through: Db.AccessList
```

Asset:

```
many_to_many :users, Db.User, join_through: Db.AccessList
many_to_many :companies, Db.Company, join_through: Db.AccessList 
many_to_many :roles, Db.Role, join_through: Db.AccessList 
many_to_many :projects, Db.Project, join_through: Db.AccessList
```

Company:

```
    many_to_many :users, Db.User, join_through: Db.AccessList
    many_to_many :assets, Db.Asset, join_through: Db.AccessList 
    many_to_many :roles, Db.Role, join_through: Db.AccessList 
    many_to_many :projects, Db.Project, join_through: Db.AccessList
```

Role:

```
    many_to_many :users, Db.User, join_through: Db.AccessList
    many_to_many :assets, Db.Asset, join_through: Db.AccessList
    many_to_many :projects, Db.Project, join_through: Db.AccessList  
    many_to_many :companies, Db.Company, join_through: Db.AccessList
```

Here is a diagram:
[image]

Comment: Would you mind to try to explicitly join `access_lists` to help Ecto?

Comment: How are the associations declared?

Comment: @MikeBuhot all of them are many to many.

Comment: @MikeBuhot the relations work fine as you can see in my answer. I don't understand why `assoc` doesn't work and the explicit path for the joins work.

Comment: @mudasobwa thank you for your hint on explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used

```
from u in User, 
        join: acl in AccessList, on: acl.user_id == u.id,
        join: c in Company, on: acl.company_id == c.id, 
        join: r in Role, on: acl.role_id == r.id, 
        join: a in Asset, on: acl.asset_id == a.id, 
        where: u.id == ^2 and a.id == ^1, 
        group_by: [c.id, u.id, r.id], 
        select: {u.email, u.id, r.name, c.name}
```

This works and I get the correct result however I am not sure why.

And why do I have to define every join and

why can't I use `join assoc` instead

Comment: Does `join: c in assoc(acl, :companies)` and similar for `roles` and `assets` work for you?

Comment: @Dogbert no it didn't. See my question `from` query. It came back with incorrect result. When I put explicitly explain the join, then it worked.

Comment: @Dogbert I have added the schema

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the schemas, it's difficult to tell, but I can make some guesses. Since `AccessList` is the join table between the `User` and companies, roles, and assets, Ecto doesn't know well enough to reuse the previous `AccessList` query in subsequent joins.

Try explicitly mapping it out like this:

```
from u in User, 
  join: acl in assoc(u, :access_lists),
  join: c in assoc(acl, :companies),
  join: r in assoc(acl, :roles),
  join: a in assoc(acl, :assets),
  where: u.id == ^2 and a.id == ^1, 
  group_by: [c.id, u.id, r.id], 
  select: {u.email, u.id, r.name, c.name}
```

Comment: this is what I am getting `could not find association `access_lists` on schema Db.User`

Comment: I have added the schema now